# Unable to install JRE 7_51 on OSX Mavericks

Tags: java, python, eclipse, macos, pydev

I have tried to install the package jre-7u51-macosx-x64.dmg because I was told Eclipse´s PyDev Python extension needs it to work on Mavericks.

Problem was that the JRE package would not even show up. The installer completed itself, the online check verified that I have the Java version installed, but when I looked in the directory it was empty! Checking with commands from terminal verified that the package could not be found from anywhere.

Is this normal for Oracle software? I have never found software that says it installed ok but cant be found from the hd...

I installed the JDK and it worked fine. Any ideas what I might have done wrong, or is the software really so bad?

Or maybe it is an Apple issue, since I had the same problme with Python 3.4 packages. It shows as installed, yet cannot be found anywhere.

Comment: Have you checked that it is in your path?
echo $PATH

Comment: Im not sure, but even if it isn't in the path the files should still be there I quess? I will repeat the whole installation process on another computer today and see what happens.

Comment: I added /Library/Java/Home to path, but JRE still does not show. Also  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler in install software did not show anything useful. So I quess its just easiest to install JDK.

Comment: It's just a bit dumb since I'm not going to develop for Java and it's 300 MB bigger package. So if anyone knows if the JRE can be made to work with Eclipse/PyDev please share your wisdom :)